# Forcing a size check of a JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, size, jinternalframe

Is there a method that will check if a JInternalFrame's size is larger than the maximum size set by `setMaximumSize`?

Currently I'm performing a `pack`;, which may result in a window that's bigger than this maximum.

Answer (score 1):

This checks if both the width **AND** height of the frame is greater than the maximum set.

```
if(frame.getWidth() > frame.getMaximumSize().getWidth() &&
   frame.getHeight() > frame.getMaximumSize().getHeight()) {

    // Do something

}
```

It is however, still possible that either the width or height is greater than the maximum set. To check if either exceeds the maximum you'll replace the `&&` (AND) with `||` (OR).